# Scrolling Text to Change Fixed Background Image on Scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, intersection-observer

I'm looking for some help, I'm trying to recreate the homepage on this site.

https://madebyarticle.com/

I don't want to use Jquery, either Plain JS or Vue.

I've got it to do most what I want it to but have a few issues.

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/JakeHenshall/pen/dyPmZmg)

HTML

```
    <main id="parent" class="Loop js-loop">
  <section>
    <h1 class="step1">One</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1 class="step2">For</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1 class="step3">All</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>And</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>All</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>For</h1>
  </section>

  <!--
  These blocks are the same as the first blocks to get that looping illusion going.
  You need to add clones to fill out a full viewport height.
  -->
  <section class="green is-clone">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="red is-clone">
    <h1>For</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```

CSS

```
    html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Loop {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
/*   min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 700px; */
  height: 100vh;
}

::scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body {
  font-family: "Avenir Next", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
/*   color: #fff; */
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mystyle {
  background: red;
}


.mystyle1 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528834379234-2de7f8328fd8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1920&q=10);
}

.mystyle2 {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501854140801-50d01698950b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2600&q=80);
}
```

JS

```
    var doc = window.document,
  context = doc.querySelector(".js-loop"),
  clones = context.querySelectorAll(".is-clone"),
  disableScroll = false,
  scrollHeight = 0,
  scrollPos = 0,
  clonesHeight = 0,
  i = 0;

function getScrollPos() {
  return (context.pageYOffset || context.scrollTop) - (context.clientTop || 0);
}

function setScrollPos(pos) {
  context.scrollTop = pos;
}

function getClonesHeight() {
  clonesHeight = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
    clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
  }

  return clonesHeight;
}

function reCalc() {
  scrollPos = getScrollPos();
  scrollHeight = context.scrollHeight;
  clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

  if (scrollPos <= 0) {
    setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
  }
}

function scrollUpdate() {
  if (!disableScroll) {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();

    if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= scrollHeight) {
      // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
      setScrollPos(1); // Scroll down 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
      disableScroll = true;
    } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
      // Scroll to the bottom when you reach the top
      setScrollPos(scrollHeight - clonesHeight);
      disableScroll = true;
    }
  }

  if (disableScroll) {
    // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      disableScroll = false;
    }, 40);
  }
}

function init() {
  reCalc();

  context.addEventListener(
    "scroll",
    function() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
    },
    false
  );

  window.addEventListener(
    "resize",
    function() {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
    },
    false
  );
}

if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
  init();
} else {
  doc.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
}

// Just for this demo: Center the middle block on page load
window.onload = function() {
  setScrollPos(
    Math.round(
      clones[0].getBoundingClientRect().top +
        getScrollPos() -
        (context.offsetHeight - clones[0].offsetHeight) / 2
    )
  );
};





const images = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      entry.target.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
});

images.forEach(image => {
  observer.observe(image);
});

const header = document.getElementById("parent");
const sectionOne = document.querySelector("h1.step1");
const sectionTwo = document.querySelector("h1.step2");
const sectionThree = document.querySelector("h1.step3");

const sectionOneObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(
  entries,
  sectionOneObserver
) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      header.classList.add("mystyle");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("mystyle");
    }
  });
});

sectionOneObserver.observe(sectionOne);

const sectionTwoObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(
  entries,
  sectionTwoObserver
) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      header.classList.add("mystyle1");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("mystyle1");
    }
  });
});

sectionTwoObserver.observe(sectionTwo);

const sectionThreeObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(
  entries,
  sectionThreeObserver
) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      header.classList.add("mystyle2");
    } else {
      header.classList.remove("mystyle2");
    }
  });
});

sectionThreeObserver.observe(sectionThree);






// if (document.querySelectorAll('h1.step1.active')){
//   document.getElementById("parent").classList.toggle("mystyle");
//   } else {
//     document.getElementById("parent").classList.remove("mystyle");
// }


// if (document.classList.contains("h1.step1.active")) {
//     document.getElementById("parent").classList.add("mystyle");
// } else {
//     document.getElementById("parent").classList.remove("mystyle");
// }
```

1. I'm having to duplicate the IntersectionObserver for every image I need, is there a cleaner way todo this?
2. At some points, there are 2 active states so it doesn't display any image only a background colour.
3. What would be the best way to fade the image on change like the example website?

Are there any examples or scripts that can do what I'm trying todo?

Thanks